# EF Core (macOS) vs sqlite database with string keys––one to many not mapped

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

This issue's taken me too much time so finally I decided to ask. I am trying to access Word property on Lookups table without success. I am able to read the columns of both Lookups and Words when I access them directly––not via navigational property. Do you have any idea what I might be doing wrong?

ps: I tried scaffolding the model and context via 'dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Data Source=vocab.db" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite -o Model' but it did not properly identify relations.

```
public class KindleContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Lookups> Lookups { get; set; }    
    public DbSet<Words> Words { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {           
        modelBuilder.Entity<Words>().HasKey(x => x.id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Lookups>().HasOne(t => t.Word).WithMany(t => t.Lookups).HasForeignKey(p => p.word_key).IsRequired();
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=vocab.db");
    }
}

public class Lookups
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string word_key { get; set; }
    public string usage { get; set; }
    public virtual Words Word { get; set; }
}

public class Words
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string word { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Lookups> Lookups { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var context = new KindleContext();

        foreach (var lookup in context.Lookups)
        {
            // Word is null
            Console.WriteLine(" - {0}", lookup.Word.word);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data). *Lazy loading is not yet possible with EF Core*, you need to use *Eager Loading*, e.g. `foreach (var lookup in context.Lookups.Include(x => x.Word))`

Comment: Thank you so much Ivan. What books/tutorials do you recommend to catch up with EF CORE?

Comment: You are welcome. I personally use only the documentation. Especially considering that EFC is actively developed and things change with each release.